# Cannot parse GraphDef file in function 'ReadTFNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie' in OpenCV-DNN TensorFlow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, attention-model

I want to wrap the [attention-OCR](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03549) model with OpenCV-DNN to increase inference time. I am using the TF code from the official TF models [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr).

For wrapping TF model with OpenCV-DNN, I am referring to this [code](https://github.com/iitzco/OpenCV-dnn-samples/blob/master/main_tensorflow.py). The `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow()` requires 'frozen graph' and 'graph structure' to read a TF model.

I use this code snippet to import structure from meta checkpoint file and save the graph structure in a `.pbtxt` file.

```
# load graph from meta file
tf.reset_default_graph()  
imported_meta = tf.train.import_meta_graph("attention_ocr_2017_08_09/model_demo_inference.ckpt.meta")

# restore graph structure, variables in session's graph
sess = tf.Session()
imported_meta.restore(sess, 'attention_ocr_2017_08_09/model_demo_inference.ckpt')
# write graph structure to a pbtxt file
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, './', 'train_attention.pbtxt', as_text=True)
```

To freeze the graph, the code is as follows:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
freeze_graph.freeze_graph('train_attention.pbtxt', '', False, \
                          'attention_ocr_2017_08_09/model_demo_inference.ckpt', \
                          'AttentionOcr_v1_1/Softmax', \
                          'save/restore_all', 'save/Const:0', 'frozen_model.pb', True, "")
```

The final code uses the `pbtxt` and `pb` files in the `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow()`function.

```
# Wrap TF model in OpenCV DNN
import cv2

FROZEN_GRAPH = "frozen_model.pb"
PB_TXT = "train_attention.pbtxt"

img = cv2.imread('testdata/fsns_train_00.png')
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1)

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(FROZEN_GRAPH, PB_TXT)
out = net.forward()
out
```

**The error encountered is:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-09e46e8b88ed> in <module>
      9 blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1)
     10 
---> 11 net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(FROZEN_GRAPH, PB_TXT)
     12 out = net.forward()
     13 out

error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/
tensorflow/tf_io.cpp:54: error: (-2:Unspecified error) 
FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param). 
Failed to parse GraphDef file: train_attention.pbtxt in function 'ReadTFNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie'
```

**Note:** The output node name is set manually by looking at the list of tensors in graph generated using:

```
# get names of all tensors
def get_names(graph=sess.graph):
    return [t.name for op in graph.get_operations() for t in op.values()]

l1 = get_names()
for ele in l1:
    print(ele)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help provided by the SO community.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was trying to access the `.pbtxt` file stored in a github repository through my Google Colaboratory.  I just needed the file, so instead of cloning the whole repo, I tried to access it using `!wget` command. I did:
`https://github.com/<username>/somethingelse/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.pbtxt`.
The file seemed to be downloaded, but when I ran `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow`, it has thrown me an error saying:

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFileTF(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/graph.pbtxt) in ReadTFNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie, file opencv-3.3.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_io.cpp, line 72
> opencv-3.3.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_io.cpp:72: error: (-2) FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFileTF(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/graph.pbtxt in function ReadTFNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie

I realised I should have used the `raw` file in github to download, as follows:

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/---somethingelse as part of link---/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.pbtxt
```

Since I didn't use raw, the file downloaded in HTML format whereas the expected file was `.pbtxt`.

**Go to the file location in github repository->click on the raw option on top right corner->get the URL of this raw page-> use**

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ ---somethingelse as part of link---/mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.pbtxt
```